# How to parse this JSON? Need logic to create HTML based on property on JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Please have a look at this JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4vpvm/

```
var data = [
    {
        description: '2ndtierchild|1sttierchild|parent',
        name: 'item1'
    },

    {
        description: '2ndtierchildagain|1sttierchild|parent',
        name: 'item2'
    },

    {
        description: 'another2ndtierchild|another1sttierchild|parent',
        name: 'item3'
    }

];
```

I want to parse this JSON to an HTML format like given below.

```
<ul>
    parent
    <li>
        1sttierchild        
        <ul>
            <li>2ndtierchild</li>
            <li>2ndtierchildagain</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        another1sttierchild        
        <ul>
            <li>another2ndtierchild</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This parsing is based on the 'description' property in JSON.

I want to split the description property and create ul-li lists based on that array of strings.

If the names are similar in the same level, it should not create a new node.

For eg. 1sttierchild is repeated in 1st level. So, you can see that, there is only one li tag created for 1sttierchild

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear how to go from the JSON you have to the format you want. Put more effort explaining, please.

Comment: Since we all love to be pedantic, that's not JSON -- it's a JavaScript array literal with object literal children.

Comment: The example you showed is an array of objects, not JSON. So your problem has nothing to do parsing JSON. Please rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: There may be a strict logic in this, but it is not very clear to us none immortals :)

Comment: Basicly he wants to build a recursive, folder-like structure from multiple paths.

Comment: So you are spliting description on the `|` character and the right-most item is that parent and so on down to the last child. Is that correct? Do you start with any of the levels built? Or do you have to build everything from scratch? Do they always have the same depth? Or does it vary?

Comment: Sorry for creating any confusion. I still think this is JSON parsing question only. @ExplosionPills: Would you please tell me what difference you see from a JSON data? Also, I wanted to give an example with this data. This is how I will get from the server.

Comment: I am working on the same. I will try to give you a fiddle with a basic approach on this. But, I am not getting a good logic for this.

Comment: @jintoppy: To understand the difference, see here: http://www.json.org/ (short version: your property keys need to be enclosed in quotes for it to be JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/4vpvm/3/

```
var root = document.getElementById("root");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    processItem(data[i].description);
}

function processItem(i) {
    var cells = i.split("|");
    var i = cells.length;
    var currNode = root;
    while (--i >= 0) {
        var node = document.getElementById(cells[i]);
        if (node === null) {
            if (!currNode.firstElementChild) {
                currNode.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
            }
            currNode = currNode.firstElementChild;
            node = document.createElement("li");
            node.id = cells[i];
            node.innerText = cells[i];
            currNode.appendChild(node);
        }
        currNode = node;
    }
}
```

This could probably be less ugly if you used jQuery, but you didn't specify so I went with vanilla JavaScript.

What it does is go through you list and for each item it will split the description string and then try to find a node (working from the end of the array back to the beginning) with a matching `id`. If it doesn't find one, it creates a new node and appends it to the parent. If the parent doesn't have any children yet, it creates and appends the extra `ul` tag. If the `id` is found, it just moves on to the next item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4vpvm/2/

```
var data = [
{
    description: '2ndtierchild|1sttierchild|parent',
    name: 'item1'
},

{
    description: '2ndtierchildagain|1sttierchild|parent',
    name: 'item2'
},

{
    description: 'another2ndtierchild|another1sttierchild|parent',
    name: 'item3'
}

];

var createUL = function(id){
$("body").append("<ul id='"+id+"'>");

$.each( data, function( index, value ){
    var list = value.description.split("|");
    $("#"+id).append("<li>" + value.name);
    $("#"+id).append("<ul id='"+value.name+"'>");
    $.each( list, function( listIndex, item ){
        $("#"+value.name).append("<li>"+item+"</li>");
    });
    $("#"+id).append("</ul>");
    $("#"+id).append("</li>");

});

$("body").append("</ul>");
};

$(document).ready(function(){
createUL("firstul");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry if I was not clear on my requirement. If the name is same on the same level, a new li node shouldn't be created. It should use the existing li node. I have edited my question like that.